# How to upload Yii project on hosting sites?

Tags: php, yii

I want to upload my Yii project on hosting sites but it seems that Yii framework is not working right in local computer. My directory structure is like this:

```
 xampp/
              htdocs/
               passcollege/
                webroot/
                 application
                 framework
```

I placed my Yii project in application folder and Yii libraries on framework folder its all working fine in my pc but when I uploaded it they (hosting site) give me a directory **/home/user/public_html**.

I placed the passcollege folder from my machine to their (hosting site) `public_html` folder, but when I accessed my site I need to manually select folders to reach Yii frameworks `index.php`.

Comment: @asieh: thanks for wanting to tidy this question. Please note that Yii (and all frameworks, software packages and languages) are proper nouns, and not I/O or code, so it does not need formatting with backticks - a capital letter is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store the framework in the web root. For the Yii application to show automatically you need to put the `index.php` file in the **/home/user/public_html** folder. I'd suggest a directory structure like this on your host:

```
/home/user/public_html
     {contents of application folder}

/home/user/framework/
```

This is the same directory for Yii to find assuming you have it set up as the default.